# extract jpeg from xlsx document with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, npm, import, xlsx

I need to import some .xlsx files in my nodejs web-app and then process the data. Some rows in the .xlsx contain images. Is it possibile to extract images from the .xlsx document and then save them in a folder?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. But that's probably not what you want to know :)

XLSX files (well, all Office *x files) are actually ZIP files; you can use any ZIP file handling library to read their contents, incl. images.